# My app scheme url is not clickable on whatsapp

Tags: ios, whatsapp

I'm trying to share my app scheme with friends on whats app, for example, if I send the link below in whats app message it will not be clickable on android and ios devices

`myapp://host`

while if I add com. like below:

`com.myapp://host`
it will work on iPhone whats app but not on android whats app